# Moving UITextView cursor to a CGPoint

Tags: cursor, uitextview, cgpoint

Am trying to make a `UITextView` behave the way the one in Notes does, i.e. you tap to make it editable (turning off the data detectors) then the cursor moves to where you tapped.

Got the tap-to-edit part working with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but how on earth do you translate the tap's `CGPoint` into a `NSRange` for moving the cursor?

I don't have the luxury of doing this under 5.0 (no `UITextInput` for the `UITextView`, ack).
Also needs to be public API's, no private stuff.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
UITextPosition * position=[textView closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 20)];
[textView setSelectedTextRange:[textView textRangeFromPosition:position toPosition:position]];
```

Comment: At the end of a line, this jumps to the next line instead of the end of the selected line. Thoughts on how to fix this?