# How to allow cursor move to any position in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cursor, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have UITextView subclass with no keyboard, that use buttons for input. I want to allow move cursor by tap to any position, not only to start or end of word. That's how it's works now:

[image]

[image]

That's what I want:

[image]

I think that solution for this problem is quite complex for beginner, so I ask you for a bit more detailed description how to do it.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338951/moving-uitextview-cursor-to-a-cgpoint)
but dont know where should I use this part of code.

---

Here is solution:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *userTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPos = [userTouch locationInView:self];
    UITextPosition *cursorPosition=[self closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(currentPos.x, currentPos.y)];
    [self setSelectedTextRange:[self textRangeFromPosition:cursorPosition toPosition:cursorPosition]];
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Because it was my own question.