# Move cursor to specific position in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

This question has been asked many times but without an actual answer to the question:

[How to allow cursor move to any position in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403000/how-to-allow-cursor-move-to-any-position-in-uitextview)

[Moving UITextView cursor to a CGPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338951/moving-uitextview-cursor-to-a-cgpoint)

I am subclassing the UITextView in iOS 7. It appears that the default behavior if a UITextView is to place the cursor at the beginning or the end of the word instead of between the characters where the user tapped.

Which methods do I need to override to do this? Or is there a bit mask that needs to be updated to define the selection behavior? I've already looked through the NSLayoutManager, NSContainer, UITextView and the NSTextStorage without finding anything obvious. Is there an example somewhere that describes how to achieve this?

Comment: FYI, in my subclass, of UITextView, I over-ride closestPositionToPoint:. I _know_ that it is giving the exact character position within the text when I tap in the view between the characters. So something else is positioning the cursor to the beginning or end of the word.

Comment: I'm almost positive it is the UITextInput caretRectForPosition: method that I need to override. The problem is, I have no idea how to get at the UITextPosition x,y. There doesn't seem to be any method to get a range or point from the UITextInput given a UITextPosition.

Comment: I just realized that all of the Apple iOS apps have this functionality. I'm not even going to worry about this. If someone has the answer, great, but it's not a big deal.